# Error while creating Hive table using dataframe schema in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to get the schema from PySpark dataframe and create Hive table using column values. Since i am partitioning the table, i have to the create the Hive table and then load data.

```
rawSchema = df.schema 
schemaString = rawSchema.fields.map(lambda field : field.name+" "+field.dataType.typeName).collect(Collectors.joining(","));      

sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hive_table COLUMNS (" + schemaString + ") PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION  Hive_table_path;"
```

But getting error in 2nd line:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

This Scala code works fine, but i need to convert it for PySpark

```
StructType my_schema = my_DF.schema();
String columns = Arrays.stream(my_schema.fields()).map(field ->field.name()+" "+field.dataType().typeName()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `create list` and then `join` the list to create `schemaString`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  a|   2|
#|  b|   3|
#+---+----+

df.schema
#StructType(List(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(name,StringType,true)))

schemaString=','.join([f.name+" "+f.dataType.typeName() for f in df.schema.fields])
#'id string,name string'

sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hive_table COLUMNS (" + schemaString + ") PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION  Hive_table_path;"

#'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hive_table COLUMNS (id string,name string) PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION  Hive_table_path;'


#Using df.dtypes

schemaString=",".join([' '.join(w) for w in df.dtypes])
#'id string,name string'

sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hive_table COLUMNS (" + schemaString + ") PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION  Hive_table_path;"
#'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hive_table COLUMNS (id string,name string) PARTITIONED BY (p int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION  Hive_table_path;'
```